# Инверсия и повторяющийся союз "и"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая между союзами, если два повторяющихся союза "и" сопровождаются инверсией - так, как это происходит в следующих стихотворных строках:

И не думаешь ты о грустном,

И живёшь - сам по себе...

С одной стороны, если убрать инверсию, может получиться: "И ты не думаешь о грустном и живёшь - сам по себе..." - тогда запятая не нужна. Но, с другой стороны, можно перефразировать и по-другому: "Ты и не думаешь.., и живёшь..." - тогда запятая необходима. Как же правильно, с запятой или без?

И что будет с запятой, если ту же схему использовать с усиленным отрицанием в первой строке ("никто"):

И не просит никто о милости,

И живёт - сам по себе...

Мне субъективно кажется, что в первом случае ("ты") запятая не нужна, а во втором ("никто") - запятая нужна, но объяснить не могу. Зато могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 2):

В обоих случаях **повторяющийся союз И...И** связывает однородные сказуемые, запятая ставится.

Кроме того, в приведенных примерах наблюдается большая расчлененность сказуемых, отсутствие их спаянности, нет общих распространителей, поэтому по структуре предложение ближе к сложному предложению, чем к предложению с однородными членами. Инверсия также способствует разобщенности сказуемых.

А простые предложения в составе **сложного** при наличии повторяющегося союза И...И также разделяются запятыми, что соответствует и паузе при  произношении.

Answer (score 1):

> > И не думаешь ты о грустном,
> >     И живёшь - сам по себе...

Это сложносочиненное предложение, вторая часть неполная (и живешь [ты] сам по себе) запятая ставится, повторяющийся союз "И" ни при чем.

Comment: Она разжала кулак и (она)  показала какие-то золотые монеты. Здесь однородные сказуемые (компактно расположенные и нераспространенные, одиночный союз И, запятая не ставится), хотя тоже можно подставить "она".  Также можно сравнить  два предложения, чтобы обозначить  влияние одиночного или повторяющегося союза на однородные сказуемые: (1) И злится метель, и воет вьюгой. (2) Метель злится и воет вьюгой. И вывод:  подстановка не всегда решает задачу, так как искажает структуру предложения, поэтому желательно провести  развернутый анализ, учесть влияние различных факторов..